# Populating django field with pre_save()?

Tags: python, database, django, model, triggers

```py
class TodoList(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(maxlength=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(maxlength=100)
    def save(self):
        self.slug = title
        super(TodoList, self).save()
```

I'm assuming the above is how to create and store a slug when a title is inserted into the table `TodoList`, if not, please correct me!

Anyhow, I've been looking into `pre_save()` as another way to do this, but can't figure out how it works.  How do you do it with `pre_save()`?

Is it like the below code snippet?

```py
def pre_save(self):
        self.slug = title
```

I'm guessing not. What is the code to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 116, accepted):

Most likely you are referring to [django's `pre_save` signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#pre-save). You could setup something like this:

```
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify

@receiver(pre_save)
def my_callback(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    instance.slug = slugify(instance.title)
```

If you dont include the sender argument in the decorator, like `@receiver(pre_save, sender=MyModel)`, the callback will be called for all models.

You can put the code in any file that is parsed during the execution of your app, `models.py` is a good place for that.

Comment: @Derek: Just override `save()`.  It's much, much simpler and more predictable.

Comment: Better? It does basically the same... If you want to change an existing app's functionality going with the signal is for sure the preferred way...

Comment: Awesome. This answer should be included in Django docs. There's really no example in docs about using `signals`.

Comment: @Firula Right, you are. I should have rather said *no **solid** example*. Thanks BTW.

Comment: Also, pre_save is called even for list updates, whereas the save method is only used when actually calling save on an instance. Thus, pre_save is the only choice if you do something like MyModel.objects.all().update(field_x=x).

Comment: @simon-steinberger pre_save is _not_ called when you use the update method on QuerySets - the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#update)  say "Finally, realize that update() does an update at the SQL level and, thus, does not call any save() methods on your models, nor does it emit the pre_save or post_save signals (which are a consequence of calling Model.save())."

Comment: @msanders do you know a way to make this work with QuerySet update method?

Answer (score 31):

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=TodoList)
def my_callback(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    instance.slug = slugify(instance.title)
```

Answer (score 19):

you can use django signals.pre_save:

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save, post_delete, pre_save

class TodoList(models.Model):
    @staticmethod
    def pre_save(sender, instance, **kwargs):
        #do anything you want

pre_save.connect(TodoList.pre_save, TodoList, dispatch_uid="sightera.yourpackage.models.TodoList")
```

Comment: For whatever reason the accepted solution did not work for me.  But, this clean and elegant solution did.

Comment: If you're going to modify the model you might as well modify the save() method. Signals should only be used if you need to decouple the code from the model.

Answer (score 16):

The [`pre_save()` signal hook](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.pre_save) is indeed a great place to handle slugification for a large number of models. The trick is to know what models need slugs generated, what field should be the basis for the slug value.

I use a class decorator for this, one that lets me mark models for auto-slug-generation, and what field to base it on:

```
from django.db import models
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.utils.text import slugify

def autoslug(fieldname):
    def decorator(model):
        # some sanity checks first
        assert hasattr(model, fieldname), f"Model has no field {fieldname!r}"
        assert hasattr(model, "slug"), "Model is missing a slug field"

        @receiver(models.signals.pre_save, sender=model, weak=False)
        def generate_slug(sender, instance, *args, raw=False, **kwargs):
            if not raw and not instance.slug:
                source = getattr(instance, fieldname)
                slug = slugify(source)
                if slug:  # not all strings result in a slug value
                    instance.slug = slug
        return model
    return decorator
```

This registers a signal handler for specific models only, and lets you vary the source field with each model decorated:

```
@autoslug("name")
class NamedModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField()

@autoslug("title")
class TitledModel(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField()
```

Note that no attempt is made to generate a *unique* slug value. That would require checking for integrity exceptions in a transaction or using a randomised value in the slug from a large enough pool as to make collisions unlikely. Integrity exception checking can only be done in the `save()` method, not in signal hooks.

Comment: I needed to add `weak=False` to the `@receiver` decorator to get this working. Local functions can be garbage collected otherwise as stated in the docs (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/signals/#module-django.db.models.signals), which prevented my functions from being called.

Comment: @Gnietschow: ah, good point! I happen to have a more involved implementation that I've simplified down for this answer, and.. that lost a reference. So I didn't run into that issue myself. I'll update the answer.

Answer (score -4):

Receiver functions must be like this:

```
def my_callback(sender, **kwargs):
    print("Request finished!")
```

Notice that the function takes a **sender** argument, along with wildcard keyword arguments **(**kwargs)**; all signal handlers must take these arguments.

All signals send **keyword arguments**, and may change those keyword arguments at any time.

Reference [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/signals/#receiver-functions).