# Add number field to Django model

Tags: python, django

I have a django movie model

```
class Film(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    movie_id = models.CharField(max_length=8, unique=True, primary_key=True)
    director = models.ForeignKey('Director', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    year = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    genres = models.ManyToManyField(Genre)
```

I need to use movie_id as primary key, but also i need a field, which represents number of item's row in table.
It must increment automatically, just like standard "id" field.
How can i add it?

This question https://stackoverflow.com/users/3404040/take-care is similar, but i can't use my "number" field as primary key, because movie_id is already used for that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make an auto increment integer field Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21128899/how-to-make-an-auto-increment-integer-field-django)

Comment: @Take_Care_ no, because i can't use this "number" field as primary key.

Comment: each model in django has by default its `id` and `pk` fields, co u can call one of them even if u didn't set AutoField manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use something like this, but it can be resource consuming if you do not want to use the default `id` field.

```
class Film(models.Model):
    def number():
        no = Film.objects.count()
        return no + 1

    movie_row = models.IntegerField(unique=True,default=number)
```

Answer (score 0):

From [Django's Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields):

> By default, Django gives each model the following field:
>
> `id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)`
>
> This is an auto-incrementing primary key.
>
> If you’d like to specify a custom primary key, just specify primary_key=True on one of your fields. If Django sees you’ve explicitly set Field.primary_key, it won’t add the automatic id column.
>
> Each model requires exactly one field to have primary_key=True (either explicitly declared or automatically added).

If you want yours to explicitly be called `movie_id` you probably need something like:

```
class Film(models.Model):
    movie_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
```