# Django models default value based on parent length

Tags: python, django, django-models, model

I'm making an app that has multiple exams and multiple questions for each exam.

This is my current 'Question' model:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    exam = models.ForeignKey(Exam, related_name='questions', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    question = models.TextField()
    explanation = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    TOPICS = [
        ('NA', 'Not Available'),
        ('Algebra', 'Algebra'),
        ('Geometry', 'Geometry'),
        ('Trig', 'Trigonometry'),
        ('Calc', 'Calculus'),
        ('Chem', 'Chemistry'),
        ('Geology', 'Geology'),
        ('Physics', 'Physics'),
        ('Reading', 'Reading'),
        ('Writing', 'Writing'),
        ('Spelling', 'Spelling'),
        ('Comprehension', 'Reading Comprehension'),
    ]
    topic = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=TOPICS, default='NA')
    order = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    attempts = models.IntegerField(default=0, editable=False)
    correct_attempts = models.IntegerField(default=0, editable=False)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ['exam', 'order']

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.exam} - Q{self.order}'
```

You can pretty much ignore all the fields except the 'order' field. This field shows what order the question will appear on the exam.

I would like for the default value of this order field to be **the number of existing questions in the exam + 1**.

For example, if my exam has two questions in it already, and I'm trying to add a third question, the order of this question will default to '3' unless I manually change it.

I know this doesn't work, but this solution would work similarly to this line of code:

```
default=Question.objects.filter(exam=self.exam).count() + 1
```

I'm inexperienced in creating functions for models in django so please let me know how I would do something like this, thanks!

Comment: maybe similer? [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21130206/16250404)

Answer (score 2):

I solved this by overriding the save() function with this:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.order = Question.objects.filter(exam=self.exam).count() + 1

        super().save(*args, **kwargs)  # Call the "real" save() method.
```