# How to get the instance of the model in clean()

Tags: django, django-models

I've overwritten the clean() method to perform a custom validation in my model. Is there any way to get the instance of the model that is being saved?

```
class Consumption(models.Model):
    storage = models.ForeignKey(Storage, related_name='consumption')
    timestamp = UnixDateTimeField()
    consumption = models.BigIntegerField(help_text='Consumption in Bytes')

    def clean(self):
        if self.storage_type == PRIMARY:
            if Storage.objects.filter(company=self.company, storage_type=PRIMARY).exists():
                raise ValidationError({'storage_type': 'Already exists a Primary storage'})
```

When I modify an Storage, which is related to a consumption, it raises the ValidationError. So I'd like to improve the filter like this:

```
Storage.objects.exclude(pk=self.instance.pk).filter(...)
```

Where can I take the instance from?

Comment: you can using [`pre_save`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/signals/#pre-save), eg is like this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/6462188/6396981

Comment: @SancaKembang how would that help ? The OP is asking how to get his model instance within the `clean` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As usual in all python instancemethods, the current instance is the first positional parameter, canonically named `self`:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    # fields etc here

    def clean(self):
       print("current instance is {}".format(self))
```

EDIT:

Since you clarified the question, it seems that what you want is the current instance's related `storage`, not the `Consumption` instance itself (which is `self`). And quite simply, since the current instance is `self`, the related `storage` instance is `self.storage`.

Comment: I've added more info to the question ;)